# How to use motion layout with recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, scroll, swipe, android-motionlayout

trying to use `MotionLayout` with `RecyclerView`,

when scrolling up, **app** is crashing with error:

> android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Unable to find
>   resource ID #0xffffffff

fragment layout code is

```
<android.support.constraint.motion.MotionLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    app:layoutDescription="@xml/collapsing_config_order_details"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    ...

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cardView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/tv_delivery_type"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/imageView15"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/view4">

     ...

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rv_list"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/cardView"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/cardView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/cardView" />

</android.support.constraint.motion.MotionLayout>
```

and layoutDescription code is:

```
<MotionScene xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <Transition
        app:constraintSetEnd="@id/collapsed"
        app:constraintSetStart="@id/expanded">

        <OnSwipe
            app:dragDirection="dragUp"
            app:touchAnchorSide="top"
            app:moveWhenScrollAtTop="@+id/rv_list" />

    </Transition>

    <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/expanded"
            android:id="@+id/cardView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/tv_delivery_type"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/imageView15"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/view4" />
    </ConstraintSet>

    <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/collapsed">
    <Constraint
            android:id="@+id/cardView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/tv_delivery_type"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/imageView15"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/view4" />
    </ConstraintSet>

</MotionScene>
```

Comment: is there a resource with id 0xffffffff in your autogenerated resources file?

Comment: no, this id is not preset in R.java

Answer (score 2):

Add `android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"` to your `recyclerView`

**works for me.**

Comment: Works for me too, tks

Comment: Did not work for me.

Answer (score 1):

```
app:moveWhenScrollAtTop="@+id/rv_list"
```

Vale of app:moveWhenScrollAtTop should be boolean.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
<ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/expanded"
            android:id="@+id/cardView"
```

to

```
<ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/expanded" >
<Constraint android:id="@+id/cardView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/tv_delivery_type"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/imageView15"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/view4" />
</ConstraintSet>
```

Answer (score 0):

Each `ConstraintSet` should have `Constraint` by themselves and you need to specify as many `Constraint` as you want to change the scene, like if you want to move A and B together with one interaction, you need to specify both of them in one `ConstraintSet`

Also, I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve, but I think you need to write code like below

```
<OnSwipe
        app:dragDirection="dragUp"
        app:touchAnchorId="@id/rv_list"
        app:touchAnchorSide="top" />
```

That means you're targeting `rv_list` to trigger the action.

Comment: Also, as you already added `viewId` in the `layout` file already, you need to change `android:id="@+id/cardView"` to `android:id="@id/cardView"`